# Does a tests submodule really reduce code bloat in Rust?

Tags: testing, rust

[Section 5.2 Testing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/testing.html) in the Rust Book says

> The [`tests`] module allows us to group all of our tests together, and to also define helper functions if needed, that don't become a part of the rest of our crate. The `cfg` attribute only compiles our test code if we're currently trying to run the tests. This can save compile time, and also ensures that our tests are entirely left out of a normal build.

I presume functions marked as `#[test]` do not appear in release builds, even if they appear in a module that does, right?  I'd expect it's just test helper functions that might waste space.  And they could be hidden individually with `#[cfg(test)]`, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can hide individual functions with `#[cfg(test)]`, and `#[test]` functions will be stripped in non-test builds (note that one can test in release mode as well!). And yes, in a release build unused functions will be optimized away. However:

- Adding a single `#[cfg(test)]` to a module is easier (and thus, is more likely to actually be done) than adding it on every single test.
- The compile-time difference still applies. In release builds, when the unused functions are stripped, they have already been analyzed, type-checked, and optimized before they get removed. It's quicker to throw the function's source code away early in the compilation process.
- Non-test debug builds matter, too --- and there, unused functions won't be removed.

Comment: I thought that `#[test]` did imply `cfg(test)`. That still doesn't deal with helper methods or glob imports though.

Comment: @Shepmaster Actually it appears you and OP are right, `#[test]` does seem to imply `#[cfg(test)]`. (A bit strange IMHO, but whatever.)